# how to retrieve post from following in these given tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Here is the database table structure I am using:

[image]

I want to perform a JOIN operation in MySQL to retrieve post for following users.

Currently I am using this query but this don't gives me the desired results.

**Query :**

```
SELECT f.userId, f.following, p.postId, p.content, p.file, p.type
FROM follow f 
JOIN post p ON p.userId = f.userId
WHERE f.userId =  '$userId' 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the posts added by users(or by followers) whom $userId follows, then you can update the `on` part of your join criteria

```
SELECT f.userId, f.following, p.postId, p.content, p.file, p.type
FROM follow f 
JOIN post p ON p.userId = f.following
WHERE f.userId =  '$userId'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Also limit without an order by makes no sense here, As there is no sample data set i assume you are storing followers as id of user in column `following` like below

```
id userId following
1   5       7
2   5       8
3   5       8
```